# Underscore template not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

In my HTML i have:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me!!"></input>

<script type="text/template" id="users-template">
<% _.each(users, function(user){ %>
    <b><%= user.name    %></b> <br />
    <%= user.city   %> <br />
    <%= user.education  %> <br />
<%});%>
</script>
```

getJSON code is :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var usertemplate = _.template($("#users-template").html());

    $.getJSON("underscoredata.php", function(data){

        var resultinghtml = usertemplate({users: data.users});

    });

});

</script>
```

From underscoredata.php i json_encode the data. The final data is:

```
{"users":[{"name":"Daniel","city":"Pune","education":"engineer"},{"name":"Joseph","city":"Bangalore","education":"Doctor"},{"name":"Radhika","city":"Delhi","education":"Actor"}]}
```

But i dont see anything in the page. How can i show the users info on the page> I have included the jquery and underscore paths.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the html resulting to DOM, create a target element:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

and append the resultinghtml

```
...
var resultinghtml = usertemplate({users: data.users});
$('#target').html(resultinghtml);
...
```

Comment: @Somename: Do you have a `#target` element? How exactly are you putting the filled in template on the page? Just filling in the template doesn't do anything useful, you have to put the resultant text somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort .. It worked with Alferdo's suggestion :)